# Golang correct filepath to serve css files

Tags: go

I have been reading and trying to serve css css files to my html page and nothing has been working . I have been reading this https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/serving-static-css-files/2051/10 to get a better understanding . My project structure is below

```
func WebRoutes(r *mux.Router) {
    r.HandleFunc("/", Index)

   // Trying to serve file here and it's not working
    r.Handle("/web/content/desktop/", http.StripPrefix("/web/content/desktop/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("desktop"))))

   // Below is the correct path since it finds the file
    _, err := os.Stat(filepath.Join(".", "/web/content/desktop/", "page.css"))
     if err != nil {
        println(err.Error())
     }

}
```

I am referencing the file from my html page like this

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Web/Content/desktop/page.css">
```

Any suggestions would be great since I can't seem to get my CSS to work .

[image]

Comment: Can you see the file in your browser. eg  http://whatever/web/content/desktop/page.css

Comment: I can not I get a 404 error

Comment: `/web/content/desktop` != `/Web/Content/desktop` and `./web/content/desktop` != `desktop` (argument to http.Dir).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're serving your static files with:

```
http.FileServer(http.Dir("desktop"))
```

But based on the screenshot the path on disk is not `"desktop"` but rather `"Web/Content/desktop"`.

Keep in mind that given that you're already using `StripPrefix`, there's no reason to use the full path unless you want to. You could do:

```
r.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("web/content/desktop"))))
```

Which would change the URL to:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/page.css">
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed it, I’m new to Golang